# same clearcase vob in two windows servers

Tags: windows, clearcase

is it possible to have a copy of the vob in a different machine for testing purpose ?

I know I can move the vob to another server using [moving a vob](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_mvvob_win_indomain.htm)

But , doing this makes the vob unavailable at the original location. So, a live vob cannot be used this way as people would be accessing it from old location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to have a copy of the vob in a different machine for testing purpose ?

Yes, the "[moving vob](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_mvvob_win_indomain.htm)" procedure would still apply.
You only need to register it to a *different* registry server, and preferably with a different tag.
That means: no need for a `-replace` option:

```
cleartool register -vob \\vobsvr01\vobstg\libpub.vbs
cleartool mktag -vob -tag \libpub \\vobsvr01\vobstg\libpub.vbs
```

That way, the live vob remains accessible.

Comment: thanks.but why do you need a different tag as its a different registry server anyway?

Comment: @user2636464 you don't indeed. I just prefer in order to make sure and know on which Vob I am working on (the test one, or the actual prod one)