# Clearcase integration with hudson for continuous integration

Tags: linux, automation, continuous-integration, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am currently having 2 linux based ClearCase servers (in same network). Server A, Server B are live ClearCase servers. Server X is a spare linux ClearCase server. Currently we are planning to install hudson on this spare server and make it as a build machine.

Hudson, using the UCM clear case plugin is able to access the VOBs and Views present only on the current machine.

My requirement is, using Hudson (on machine X) I need to setup continuous integration on the VOBs present on server A and server B using X as the build machine.

1. How to access remote vobs and views on my build machine. (Without using unix mount). Is it possible to connect to the remote cc machine using the URL that we use to connect using the CTE.
2. Should I use dynamic view or snapshot view for the build purpose. Is there any best practice prescribed for this scenario.  I am not planning to do anything except build and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

> 1/ How to access remote vobs and views on my build machine. (Without using unix mount)

Simply use the ClearCase on server X as a client, and declare in it the Vobs from serverA  and serverB (mktag and register, as I mentioned in "[same clearcase vob in two windows servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431876/6309)")

Then you can create your own views on serverX, referencing those Vobs and PVobs.

> 2/ Should I use dynamic view or snapshot view for the build purpose. Is there any best practice priscribed for this scenario.

If you only read the sources from those views *and* are doing the actual build *outside* of the view, then a dynamic view is fine.
If the build (which is a writing operation) takes place within the ClearCase view itself, then the view *has to be* a **[snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309)**.

Answer (score 0):

1) If Server A and Server B use the same registry server, it will be simpler. In that case, the Hudson server has to be the client of that  registry server.
If Server A and Server B have their own registry server, you can still do it.
Say you want to set registry of Server A as the main registry server. You have to declare Vobs of Server B in registry A (register and mktag the VOBs from Server B on Server A by specifying that the host is Server B). If you do not want to pollute the default region of Server A, you can create a dedicated region (cleartool mkregion) where you will mktag VOBs from both Servers). Then on Hudson server, you will have to specify that you are the client from Server A using registry A and that specific region. You will then see VObs from server A and server B.

2) Snapshot view. If you read [wiki page about clearcase ucm Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin), it explains why snapshot build is used. "Snapshot views can - as opposed to dynamic views - be located anywhere, which we exploit to place it inside the job's workspace." "In general build performance is also much better in snapshot views that are hosted by the clients native file system - once they are loaded."

Answer (score 0):

May I write a suggestion ...

We forked the ClearCase plugin few years ago to enable Windows and linux ClearCase Snapshot support with base ClearCase and UCM ClearCase.

We added the support of snapshot views and Dynamic views (with a forced Workspace relocation checkbox) (windows as well as linux)

We added the support of ClearQuest ticket tracking through activitises.
We added the support ok complex baselining features.
We added a pretested commit feature enabling deliverComplete postaction in case of build success. and promoting baseline.

Maybe this plugin will help ... 
Maybe someone should be enough interested to pariticipate to its evolution.

I give you the link : https://github.com/cittools/clearcase-plugin
Any feedback is welcome
(I am brand new on stackoverflow, if I missed a rule, guide me)